# Php pdf how to insert an image as table background

Tags: php, image, pdf, background

I've just startted creating pdf files in php and I was wondering if I can add a background image to  a table. What I want to do basically is create an invoice and in it have a table with curved corners and in this table I have lines showing details of purchased items. I searched and found that I can create cells and lines but not a table with dynamic cells in it. So I thought maybe I can set the table outline as the background image and then create cells on it.

[image]

Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to create the PDFs?

Comment: @jprofitt actually I'm working on a script provided by prestashop which uses fpdf.php. I'm new to it so I'm sorry I can't answer your question precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the background image and adding cells with outline.